# MSSQL Row_Number() over(order by) in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

i need to make a group by clause with the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(donationvalue) FROM tbl_pdm2k10_Donations
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY SUM(donationvalue) desc
```

but i want a column on the left returning me: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc as as result.
In MSSql i would do

```
  SELECT Row_Number() Over(order by SUM(donationvalue) desc), NAME, SUM(donationvalue)      
 FROM tbl_pdm2k10_Donations
    GROUP BY NAME
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set @row:=0;
SELECT 
  @row:=@row+1 as row_numer,
  NAME, 
  SUM(donationvalue) as total 
FROM tbl_pdm2k10_Donations
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY total desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes (using a variable)

See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/