# MySQL sort differently in "batch"

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the standard query that sort weight in descending order.

```
SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 0, 4
+-------------+--------+
| title       | weight |
+-------------+--------+
| B           | 2      | 
| E           | 2      | 
| Y           | 2      | 
| A           | 1      | 
| C           | 1      | 
| D           | 1      | 
| F           | 1      | 
| G           | 1      | 
| X           | 1      | 
| Z           | 1      | 
| I           | 1      | 
| G           | 1      | 
+-------------+--------+
```

However, I wish to sort it differently as following based on the weight value.

```
+-------------+--------+
| title       | weight |
+-------------+--------+
| B           | 2      | 
| A           | 1      | 
| C           | 1      | 
| D           | 1      | 
| E           | 2      | 
| F           | 1      | 
| G           | 1      | 
| X           | 1      | 
| Y           | 2      | 
| Z           | 1      | 
| I           | 1      | 
| G           | 1      | 
+-------------+--------+
```

The record with weight value 2 only selected once and sorted at the top. Then followed by records with weight value 1.

Comment: Try to rephrase the question. For now there is no clear explanation what you want to sort and how.

Comment: You are asking for an answer that describes an operation (a sort) without ambiguity. You should provide information of the same quality standard.

Comment: please show the entire table structure. How is decided to be B,A,C,D,E the correct order, and not B,F,G,X,E ?

Comment: Your second table makes no sense. There is no discernable pattern that could be used to create a sort clause - if you were sorting by weight, then the two `G` titles would be together.

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach like in these answers:

- [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127)
- [MSSQL Row_Number() over(order by) in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571317/mssql-row-number-overorder-by-in-mysql/4571326#4571326)

you could obtain row numbers, separately, for rows with weight value of 2 and for rows with any other weight value, then use the resulting numbers for sorting.

Before I continue, please note that, even though the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) admits that

> You might get the results you expect,

it also advises that,

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

(By *the same statement* it means a statement other than `SET`.)

Below is a way of getting the expected order *if* the results are as they are expected.

```
SET @row2 = -1;
SET @row_other = -1;

SELECT
  title, weight
FROM (
  SELECT
    title, weight,
    @row2 := @row2 + CASE weight WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS weight2_row,
    @row_other := @row_other + CASE weight WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS other_weight_row
  FROM article
) s
ORDER BY
  CASE weight WHEN 2 THEN @row2 ELSE @row_other DIV 3 END,
  weight = 2 DESC
```

The specific order for non-`Weight=2` rows is undefined, just like it is in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the same precautions that Andriy states, you can also use this:

```
SELECT title, weight
FROM
    ( SELECT title, weight
           , @rownumber2 := @rownumber2 + 3 AS rn
      FROM article
         , ( SELECT @rownumber2 := 1 ) AS dummy
      WHERE weight = 2
      ORDER BY title                     --- optional, configure it for the 
                                         --- ordering of rows with weight = 2
    UNION ALL

      SELECT title, weight
           , @rownumber1 := @rownumber1 + 1 AS rn
      FROM article
         , ( SELECT @rownumber1 := 3 ) AS dummy
      WHERE weight = 1
      ORDER BY title DESC                --- optional, configure it for the 
                                         --- ordering of rows with weight = 1
    ) AS insaneOrdering

ORDER BY rn
       , weight DESC ;
```

Comment: `(SELECT @rownumber2 := 0)` and then `… @rownumber2 := @rownumber2 + 4`, and for @rownumber1: `(SELECT @rownumber1 := -1)`, `… @rownumber1 := @rownumber1 + 1 + ((@rownumber + 4) % 4 = 3)`, if you meant assigning something like `0, 4, 8 …` to @rownumber2 and everything else (`1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, …`) to @rownumber1. But maybe you are implementing something different here.

Comment: @Andriy: I'm trying `rn=4,7,10,...` with `weight=2` and `rn=4,5,6,7,...` with `weight=1`. I'm sure there are many ways to achieve same result.