# MySQL Add rownumbers per ID

Tags: mysql, sessionid, row-number

I have a table test with sessionIDs. I want to group the IDs and add rownumbers to each record per ID. I used [MSSQL Row_Number() over(order by) in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571317/mssql-row-number-overorder-by-in-mysql) and added an if-statement (to group per session_ID). However, it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
SET @row:=0
SET @sessionID:=0

SELECT 
    session_ID
    @row:=if(@sessionID = session_ID, @row+1, 1) AS row_num
    @sessionID := session_ID
FROM test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma after `row_num` and you need an `order by`:

```
SET @row:=0;
SET @sessionID:=0;

SELECT 
    session_ID,
    @row:=if(@sessionID = session_ID, @row+1, 1) AS row_num,
    @sessionID := session_ID
FROM test
ORDER BY session_ID;
```

You can write this as a single query:

```
SELECT session_ID,
       @row:=if(@sessionID = session_ID, @row+1, 1) AS row_num,
       @sessionID := session_ID
FROM test cross join
     (select @row := 0, @sessionID := 0)
ORDER BY session_ID;
```

Comment: Thnx, it's working. After de SELECT session_id an comma is missing.