# Add ascending number (per ID) in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have a table with articlenumbers and a number of specific codes.

Now I would like to add an ascending number to the articles, restarting on each new article.

For example my list is:

```
A 1234
A 4321
A 1233
B 1222
B 2222
C 1111
D 1258
D 1285
```

I would like to add the last number, like this:

```
A 1234 1
A 4321 2
A 1233 3
B 1222 1
B 2222 2
C 1111 1
D 1258 1
D 1285 2
```

It's a simple table, so the select for the first part is:

```
SELECT ART, CODE FROM tblArtCodes ORDER BY ART
```

I checked the following link - [MySQL Add rownumbers per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408994/mysql-add-rownumbers-per-id)
But couldn't get it to work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mysql version is lower than 8 then you should use subquery as follows:

```
SELECT ART, CODE,
       (Select count(*) from tblArtCodes tt
         Where t.art = tt.art and t.code >= tt.code) as rn
 FROM tblArtCodes t ORDER BY ART, rn
```

If you are on mysql 8 or higher then you can use `row_number` as follows:

```
SELECT ART, CODE,
       Row_number() over (partition by art order by code) as rn
FROM tblArtCodes t ORDER BY ART, rn
```