# laravel get row number of a specific record

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table `queue` and I want to know what position or row number a `user` at.

queue table

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id  |  name  |        created_at       |   done  |
+-----+--------+-------------------------+---------+
|  1  |  John  |   2020-10-17 01:08:59   |    1    |
|  2  |  Jane  |   2020-10-17 01:10:15   |    0    |
|  3  |  Jess  |   2020-10-17 01:18:15   |    0    |
|  4  |  Joe   |   2020-10-18 08:18:15   |    0    |
|  5  |  Moe   |   2020-10-18 11:18:15   |    0    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

is it possible to know the specific number of user in `queue`? for example `Jess` will return `3` because he's the `3rd` user in the queue record.

edit: for example `John` is done in the queue, now `Jess` will become the `2nd` in the queue.

Comment: `$q = Queue::where('name', 'Jess')->first();` then `$id = $q->id;` `$id` will return `3`

Comment: is there any approach for that? what if it's a different `id`?

Comment: You mean, if you delete the `John` then, `Jess` will return `2`, instead of `3`? Because, `Jess` on the second position now

Comment: yes exactly you got it

Comment: i've edited my question to elaborate more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel how do I get the row number of an object using Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408091/laravel-how-do-i-get-the-row-number-of-an-object-using-eloquent)

Comment: @OMR I tried with `Product::selectRaw('*, @row:=@row+1 as row')->get();` but all `row` returns null

Comment: oh, so it's not applicable, thank you for trying @sta

Comment: @konjesh you may try on your side, idk why all row returns null here

Comment: @OMR that's not working, it think it's because it's an answer from `2014`

Answer (score 3):

I think I have a way:

the main idea is to get the count of the previous queue based on their id values,
and the trick is to use an alias to the main table so you can use that alias in your internal select.

```
   $values = DB::table('queue', 'u1')
            ->select('u1.id',DB::raw("((SELECT count(*) from queue WHERE queue.id < u1.id)+1) rowNumber"))
            ->orderBy('u1.id')
            ->get();
```

**Edit:**

if you want to exclude done queue you should do it in the main and the internal select:

```
 $values = DB::table('queue', 'u1')
            ->select('u1.id',DB::raw("((SELECT count(*) from queue WHERE (queue.id < u1.id)and(queue.is_done!=1) )+1) rowNumber"))
            ->where('u1.is_done','!=',1)
            ->orderBy('u1.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: this is a little bit close to what I am trying to achieve. actually I need to filter `done = 0`, but when I try in based on your answer, it still preserved the number of row where he is, not calculating where he was at after the `done` user in queue, I mean I need to recount and adjust the `rowNumber` once a user is done in queue

Comment: I mean, I need to exclude the `done` in queue they're `NOT` be counted in `rowNumber`

Comment: This is a nice solution. Once you pair it with your Eloquent model as a scope and build the subquery using the syntax `$query->addSelect(['position' => ...build query here...])` you will have an elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to get that number directly with query you can do
[search()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-search)

```
$collection->search(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->name == 'Jess';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering @Osta, but I think you don't understand the question fully.