# How to get row number of a row in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I can return an object using -

```
$firstUnseenMessage = Message::where(['sender_id' => $id, 'receiver_id' => auth()->id(), 'seen' => 0])->first();
```

But I want to get the number at which this row exists from the top.

Comment: `$firstUnseenMessage->id` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel how do I get the row number of an object using Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408091/laravel-how-do-i-get-the-row-number-of-an-object-using-eloquent)

Comment: No, I don't want the id, because it may not be the actual position from the top if some records are deleted. I want the actual position from the top of the table of a row.